# USB-device on SAM3-H256 - advice?

Tags: usb-device

I want to build a device which should act as a USB keyboard. I've found a
[SAM3-H256](http://olimex.com/dev/sam3-h256.html) board to be fairly easily available in my country. I want the device to be:

- fully USB-powered (no additional power sources),
- fully USB-programmable (from PC; no JTAG or other external debuggers), using free tools (e.g. GCC),
- not to have to attach any additional elements (apart from a few on/off keys to be used to trigger sending keycodes to PC), especially not to need anything additional to make it to work over USB.

I'm a newbie in electronics, and therefore I'd like to ask what would be the most serious problems I should expect to face with this board and requirements as described? Or shouldn't I expect it to work in such a configuration at all?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better check examples bundled with this board. If it have any examples on HID devices (i.e. keyboard, mouse) - you are good to go. If there are no working examples - it might be hard to figure it out how to make it work from scratch.

Personally, I've implemented USB-keyboard emulator on V-USB library: http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/easylogger.html - it works on nearly any atmega device. So you can for example get Arduino board and go from there.